# ChIP-seq data Analysis Database

Tags: chip-seq

Where can i find already analyzed ChIP-Seq Data? Is there any database or any web tool that takes ChIP-seq raw data and automatically analyzes them? Or is there any database that provides some API to analyze the raw data it provides. I am new to ChIP-seq data analysis and i really need these to create a web-based platform for mapping ChIP-seq data. Thanks in advance.
I found some interesting data in genome.edu. Is there another database?

Comment: do you mean UCSC genome browser by genome.edu? It actually incorporates data from the ENCODE ChIP-seq experiments.

Answer (score 2):

The largest database of curated ChIP-seq data is currently [Encode](https://www.encodeproject.org/) and it supports an API.  You can use JSON to get at all tracks.

That page will have a link to [Getting Started](https://www.encodeproject.org/help/getting-started/) that should get you going. You can visualize raw data, normalized data, and processed data tracks in genome browsers that load in ENCODE data.  My favorite genome browser is:

[WashU Epigenome browser](http://epigenomegateway.wustl.edu/browser/)